# Postgresql Multiple counts for one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, group-by

From two columns in my table I want to get a unified count for the values in these columns.
As an example, two columns are:

Table: reports

```
|   type        |   place   |  
 ----------------------------------------- 
|   one         |   home    |  
|   two         |   school  |  
|   three       |   work    |  
|   four        |   cafe    |  
|   five        |   friends |  
|   six         |   mall    |  
|   one         |   work    |  
|   one         |   work    |  
|   three       |   work    |  
|   two         |   cafe    |  
|   five        |   cafe    |  
|   one         |   home    |
```

If I do:
SELECT type, count(*) from reports
group by type

I get:

```
|   type        |   count   |  
-----------------------------  
|   one         |   4       |  
|   two         |   2       |  
|   three       |   2       |  
|   four        |   1       |  
|   five        |   2       |  
|   six         |   1       |
```

Im trying to get something like this: (one rightmost column with my types grouped together and multiple columns with the count vales for each place)
I get:

```
|   type        |   home    |   school  |   work    |   cafe    |   friends |   mall    |  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
|   one         |   2       |           |   2       |           |           |           |  
|   two         |           |   1       |           |   1       |           |           |  
|   three       |           |           |   2       |           |           |           |  
|   four        |           |           |           |   1       |           |           |  
|   five        |           |           |           |   1       |   1       |           |  
|   six         |           |           |           |           |           |   1       |
```

which would be the result of running a count like the one above for every place like this:

```
SELECT type, count(*) from reports where place  = 'home'
group by type
SELECT type, count(*) from reports where place  = 'school'
group by type
SELECT type, count(*) from reports where place  = 'work'
group by type
SELECT type, count(*) from reports where place  = 'cafe'
group by type
SELECT type, count(*) from reports where place  = 'friends'
group by type
SELECT type, count(*) from reports where place  = 'mall'
group by type
```

Is this possible with postgresql?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here we have some definitive lookup right. eg( 'home','school' ...)
i have the situtation lookup may know at runtime only.
any template sql for that?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

you can use `case` in this case -

```
SELECT type, 
       sum(case when place  = 'home' then 1 else 0 end) as Home,
       sum(case when  place  = 'school' then 1 else 0 end) as school,
       sum(case when  place  = 'work' then 1 else 0 end) as work,
       sum(case when  place  = 'cafe' then 1 else 0 end) as cafe,
       sum(case when  place  = 'friends' then 1 else 0 end) as friends,
       sum(case when  place  = 'mall' then 1 else 0 end) as mall
  from reports
 group by type
```

It should solve your problem

@S T Mohammed,
To get such type we can simply use `using` after `group` or `where` condition in outer query, as below -

```
select type, Home, school, work, cafe, friends, mall from (
SELECT type, 
       sum(case when place  = 'home' then 1 else 0 end) as Home,
       sum(case when  place  = 'school' then 1 else 0 end) as school,
       sum(case when  place  = 'work' then 1 else 0 end) as work,
       sum(case when  place  = 'cafe' then 1 else 0 end) as cafe,
       sum(case when  place  = 'friends' then 1 else 0 end) as friends,
       sum(case when  place  = 'mall' then 1 else 0 end) as mall
  from reports
 group by type
 )
 where home >0 and School >0 and Work >0 and cafe>0 and friends>0 and mall>0
```

Comment: To get blank (null) columns instead of zero, wrap the sums in `nullif` calls. Using `count` with `null` instead of `0` (by omitting the `ELSE 0` entirely) for the failed case works fine too, you don't have to change to `sum`.

Comment: The last comma in the sql statement (right before the "from" keyword) causes an error.

Comment: how to get records for where home,school,work,cafe,friends,mall values >0

Comment: apologies for this late reply. By doing small change in query you can get output as what you want.

Answer (score 31):

Answer by praktik garg is correct, it is not necessary to use `else 0`:

```
SELECT type, 
       sum(case when place  = 'home' then 1 end) as home,
       sum(case when  place  = 'school' then 1 end) as school,
       sum(case when  place  = 'work' then 1 end) as work,
       sum(case when  place  = 'cafe' then 1 end) as cafe,
       sum(case when  place  = 'friends' then 1 end) as friends,
       sum(case when  place  = 'mall' then 1 end) as mall
FROM reports
GROUP BY type
```

You can also use the following even shorter syntax:

```
SELECT type, 
       sum((place  = 'home')::int) as home,
       sum((place  = 'school')::int) as school,
       sum((place  = 'work' )::int) as work,
       sum((place  = 'cafe' )::int) as cafe,
       sum((place  = 'friends')::int) as friends,
       sum((place  = 'mall')::int) as mall
FROM reports
GROUP BY type
```

This will work because boolean `true` is cast to `1` when condition is met.

Answer (score 24):

You can use filter clause as well:

```
SELECT
  type,
  sum(1) FILTER (WHERE place = 'home') AS home,
  sum(1) FILTER (WHERE place = 'school') AS school,
  sum(1) FILTER (WHERE place = 'work') AS work,
  sum(1) FILTER (WHERE place = 'cafe') AS cafe,
  sum(1) FILTER (WHERE place = 'friends') AS friends,
  sum(1) FILTER (WHERE place = 'mall') AS mall
FROM
  reports
GROUP BY 
  type
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `filter` and `count` like this:

```
select type,
       count(1) FILTER (where place = 'home') as home,
       count(1) FILTER (where place = 'school') as school,
       count(1) FILTER (where place = 'work') as work,
       count(1) FILTER (where place = 'cafe') as cafe,
       count(1) FILTER (where place = 'friends') as friends,
       count(1) FILTER (where place = 'mall') as mall
from reports
group by type
```

Comment: This should get more upvotes! `FILTER` works beautifully with aggregates!